# SQLite Upsert - syntax error

Tags: sqlite, upsert

I'm trying to use SQLite's upsert syntax as described [in their documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html)

However I get the following error, in both WebSql (SQLite v3.41.2) and SQLite on Android (SQLite v3.40.0)

```
could not prepare statement (1 near \"DO\": syntax error)
```

The error suggests this syntax isn't supported but UPSERT support was added in 3.24.0.

I also tested the exact query I'm using on [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LC7RWg2g) and it runs fine,

I'm lost!

/edit

The query was in the dbFiddle, but for clarity, I'm using [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) with the [SQLite plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/sqlite). Given the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Drawings(
id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
title TEXT NOT NULL, 
fileId TEXT NOT NULL, 
documentUrl TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Running the following query

```
INSERT INTO Drawings(id, title, fileId, documentURL) 
VALUES(1,'asd','asd123123asd','qwefdfg') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET title = excluded.title, fileId = excluded.fileId, documentURL = excluded.documentUrl
```

Yields the error

```
could not prepare statement (1 near \"DO\": syntax error)
```

Basically it seems that the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` isn't supported but that was added in SQLite 3.24.0 and I'm testing in 3.41.2 (WebSQL) and 3.40.0 (Android API 34)

Comment: Please show us your query. How else can we know whats wrong with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.